# Failing to install LTM in R

Tags: r

I'm a complete beginner with R and any kind of programming really, and struggling with installing the `LTM` package for use in making a rasch analysis in SPSS 26.

I've used the command

```
install.packages("ltm")
```

tried in R3.3, 3.5 and 3.6 (all in MS windows) as these are compatible with the versions of SPSS I have access to, and get the following output returned:

```
*Installing package into ‘C:/Users/info/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘admisc’, ‘polycor’   There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation admisc     0.8   0.28             FALSE polycor 0.7-10  0.8-1             FALSE ltm      1.1-1  1.2-0    FALSE installing the source packages ‘admisc’, ‘polycor’, ‘ltm’ trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/admisc_0.28.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 58877 bytes (57 KB) downloaded 57 KB trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/polycor_0.8-1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13931 bytes (13 KB) downloaded 13 KB trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/ltm_1.2-0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 287001 bytes (280 KB) downloaded 280 KB
* installing *source* package 'admisc' ...
** package 'admisc' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
*** arch - i386 Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'admisc'
* removing 'C:/Users/info/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/admisc'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/info/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/admisc' In R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package 'polycor' ...
** package 'polycor' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    namespace 'admisc' 0.8 is being loaded, but >= 0.22 is required ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'polycor'
* removing 'C:/Users/info/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/polycor' In R CMD INSTALL ERROR: dependency 'polycor' is not available for package 'ltm'
* removing 'C:/Users/info/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ltm' In R CMD INSTALL The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\info\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc5HpAg\downloaded_packages’ Warning messages: 1: In install.packages("ltm") :   installation of package ‘admisc’ had non-zero exit status 2: In install.packages("ltm") :   installation of package ‘polycor’ had non-zero exit status 3: In install.packages("ltm") :   installation of package ‘ltm’ had non-zero exit status*
```

I've also attempted to install earlier versions of `admisc` and `polycor` but get an error message that they are not available with this version of R.

Hope somebody can spot what I'm doing wrong here!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you need to install rtools, which will allow you to build packages from source.

Comment: @AllanCameron is correct. Also, when asked, you can choose the binary version rather the source version. The binary version is pre-compiled, whiereas the source version (often more recent) requires compilation and additional software, whence rtools.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `'make' not found` suggests that you need to install Rtools to be able to build packages in Windows.

Since you are using an old R version you also need older Rtools version like Rtools35, found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html).

When installing Rtools remember to add rtools to Path using the checkbox in the dialog similar to that one.

[image]